# MongoDB: Declarative or Navigational?

Tags: mongodb

I am still new on the whole area of MongoDB systems.

I was wondering whether anyone of you knows if MongoDB is declarative or navigational when it comes to accessing objects within a document?

What I mean is:
-> Declarative: a pattern is given and the system works out the result.  In other words, it works in the same way as SPJ queries
-> Navigational: it always starts from the beginning of a document and continues from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPJ (Select-Project-Join) is more than just accession of documents/rows, it is the entire process of forming a result set for queries.

I am unsure how the two: "Declarative" and "Navigational" are compatible. You talk about "Declarative" being the formation of a result set but then "Navigational" being related to accessing a document, i.e. reading the beginning of it.

I will answer what I believe your question to be about, the access patterns of documents.

I believe MongoDB leaves reading up to the OS itself (might use some C++ library to do its work for it) as such it starts from the beginning of a pointer (i.e. "Navigational") however, as to how it actually reads document does not really matter.

Here is why, MongoDB does not split a document up into many pieces to be stored on the hard disk, instead it stores a document as a single "block" of space. So I am going to turn around and say you probably need to look at the code to be sure exactly how it reads, though I don't see the point and here is a presentation that will help you understand more about the internals of MongoDB: http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/storage-engine-internals